# Why is there a "X-second buffer" on bodycams?

Tags: united-states, police, recording

I've seen numerous bodycam videos.

They frequently mention that "there is no audio for the first 30 seconds" (sometimes different number of seconds), so the video is muted initially.

What is the purpose of this "feature"? Why record "half-assedly" like that? Why is it not either on or off, where on means "audio + video" and off means "all off"? Why is such a "buffer" needed? It certainly cannot be for any technical reason.

Comment: I would guess because the camera is always recording and the audio doesn't start until it is triggered. The 30 second buffer comes from the last 30 seconds being stored when it is triggered.

Comment: Actually it *is* a technical, not a legal reason: video files with audio are much larger than just video files, as audio data is actually more complex than video: video is one data point per pixel and frame. But Audio has a several dozen times denser data frequency than frames and stores more than just the amplitude (~color).

Comment: @Trish Technical in what way? That it takes 30 seconds for the audio to turn on? That they are always recording but only have audio on when triggered?

Comment: @trish for a given quality level video takes much more bandwidth than audio. Think of an audio cassette vs a VHS tape. One is much larger and more complicated due to including video.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite It's not actually a good comparison: VHS tapes run at a different speed than cassettes. A VHS needs 126 meters for 63 minutes or about 2 meter per minute. Cassettes require about 86 meters for 60 minutes or about 1.5 meters per minute.

Comment: I was trying to come up with a tangible comparison rather than go into technicalities. Even by that data audio would comparable to video not "several dozen times denser". In fact video is much more complex than audio and amplitude over time is all it takes to record, store and reproduce audio. It's easy to look up or ask an electrical engineer.

Comment: @Trish I am sorry but I don't buy that audio takes up more space then video (a lot will depend on the quality) can you provide some sources for this claim?

Comment: @JoeW: As an example in the opposite direction, [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en#zippy=%2Cbitrate) are YouTube's bitrate guidelines, which should be a pretty good indicator of common practice.  Taking for instance 720p SDR video at standard frame rate and stereo audio, they recommend 5 Mbps for video and 384 kbps for audio.  So the video uses some 13 times more space than the audio.

Comment: @Trish video takes *much* more bandwidth than audio. Video signals with the bandwidth of voice signals are extremely low quality and/or have frame rates measured in second or even minutes per frame.

Comment: Audio recordings *are* just the amplitude recorded several thousand times per second. That's a lot more individual "frames" than video, which is normally anywhere from 20 to 60 frames per second, but each "frame" is a single number, whereas each frame of a video is a distinct photograph.

Answer (score 5):

Retaining video from the buffer period advances law-enforcement and accountability purposes by making it more likely that the camera will retain footage of whatever caused the officer to turn the camera on in the first place.

If a police officer says you ran a red light, the dash camera will show what actually happened if the officer turned it on within 30 seconds of you passing through the intersection. If a corrections officer says he had to use force because an inmate jumped him, the buffer period allows the camera to capture not just the officer hitting the inmate, but also whatever happened immediately prior.

[According to Axon](https://chicago.suntimes.com/2018/7/17/18405204/cpd-supt-johnson-explains-why-no-audio-recovered-from-fatal-police-shooting#:%7E:text=Steve%20Tuttle%2C%20spokesman%20for%20Axon,an%20audio%2Dfree%20video%20buffer.), which seems to have largest market share in the BWC space, the lack of audio is meant to protect the officers' privacy:

> Cops feared they might tell a joke or discuss a personal situation like a divorce before they double-pressed the large button on the device to activate it. They didn’t want their private conversations to become public along with the buffer that preserves 30 seconds of video before the device is activated

Answer (score 1):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

It depends on the particular policies and operating procedures of the various police forces (or government agencies) that use body worn video devices whether the "pre-event recording buffer<sup>1</sup>" is soley video or captures audio as well.

For example, the [Metropolitan Police](https://www.policeprofessional.com/news/mps-doubles-pre-event-buffering-on-body-worn-video-units/) say:

> All BWV cameras operate in standby mode in which they capture video but not audio. This video is not saved but overwrites itself until an officer presses the record button. At this point, the buffered material is saved and attached to the recording. Audio is captured only when the record button is pressed.

Whereas [Dorset Police](https://www.dorset.police.uk/news-information/body-worn-video/frequently-asked-questions/)'s policy is:

> The camera records a rolling 30 second loop of film in standby mode so when a recording starts the previous 30 seconds of audio and video are always captured.

---

<sup>1</sup>Defined by the [Technical Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/technical-guidance-for-body-worn-video-bwv-devices-cast-2018) as:

> A continuous recording loop designed to ensure that relevant information is still captured if the User is unable to immediately activate the recording